# How to modify a POST request in tastypie?

Tags: tastypie, datatables

I am using tastypie0.10.0 on the server side and jquery.datatables.editable2.3.3 on client side.
My issue is how can i insert {columnName : value} object into tastypie to update the record  since the editable plugin sends form data as

value:textEntered
id:628
columnName:long_name
rowId:0
columnPosition:4
columnId:4

where am I going wrong?Please Help
Here is my datatables.makeEditable code

```
 $('#table_id').dataTable().makeEditable({
        sAddURL: "/api/v1/project/?format=json",
        sDeleteURL: "/api/v1/project/?format=json",
        sUpdateURL:  "/api/v1/project/?format=json",
        sDeleteHttpMethod : "DELETE",

});
```

And tastypie code

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'project'
        authorization= Authorization()
        paginator_class = Paginator
        default_format = "application/json"
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete','patch']
        excludes =["slug","supervisor","client_id"]
        filtering = {
            #'date_created' : 'icontains',
            'initials' : 'iexact',
            'short_name':['icontains','istartswith','exact'],
            'id' :'exact',
            'long_name':['icontains','istartswith','exact'],
        }

        def obj_update(self, bundle, request, **kwargs):
            bundle = super(ProjectResource, self).obj_update(bundle, request,**kwargs)
                cn = bundle.request.POST.get('columnName')
                v = bundle. request.POST.get('value')
                foo ={cn:v}
                bundle = self.build_bundle(data=foo,request=request,**kwargs)
                bundle.obj.save()
            return bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `cn` is not `None`, how about,

```
    def obj_update(self, bundle, request, **kwargs):
        base_bundle = super(ProjectResource, self).obj_update(bundle, request,**kwargs)
        foo = base_bundle.request.POST.copy()
        cn = foo.pop('columnName')
        v = foo.pop('value')
        foo.update({cn:v})
        bundle = self.build_bundle(data=foo,request=request,**kwargs)
        bundle.obj.save()
        return bundle
```

Comment: This code is not working.Is there any reason why you chose to make  a  copy and pop of the POST.I thought i had missed the foo.update() and expected this to work,but it didn't.Any way i came across a "solution " i am posting below.

Comment: creating `copy()` of POST is the common way to modify POST. And I `pop` the POST because both `columnName` and `value` is not required anymore.

Comment: OK i am sorry aditya ,I think i was way off in my approach.I changed the supdateurl to **"/api/v1/project/626/?format=json"** to send a PATCH request to a detail endpoint.And i am issuing a ajax request from __makeEditable__.And I'm back to using your solution,but 'am getting a new error   **"build_bundle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'"** and it is still not updating the db .Any idea?  PS: The request method now shows as **PATCH**

Comment: To edit an object, you should use `PUT` not `PATCH` (PATCHing is still debatable because not all browsers support this method).

And, you can access your request data using `bundle.data` no matter your request method.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a solution that i am not completely sure is the right approach.But it worked in that its atleast saving the object and updating the table on the client side...  This is a bare minimum working code without error handling and other checks,(so guide me if i am missing anything).

```
def hydrate(self, bundle):
    cn = bundle.request.POST.get('columnName')
    v = bundle.request.POST.get('value')
    setattr(bundle.obj, cn, v) # this works
    #bundle.data[cn]=v # this also works 
    #bundle.obj.save() # no need to call save 
    return bundle
```

However I was looking at **updating** as against creating, the reason why i was trying to use **obj_update**.Now i am lost on the approach i should take, and how i can issue a **PATCH** request from datatables.makeEditable().I have tried passing aoColumn :[....,{"method" : "PUT"},...] but
The browser reports the   request as POST.

> Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:201 CREATED

**EDIT**
Still stuck with this.The hydrate solution updates the table cell,but changes all other fields to their default values.Which means that it is creating the row and not updating it.

I am not sure if its jquery.datatables.editable issue or a tastypie issue.
Somebody please please Help.